# c#: How can you log into and administer a Linux server programmatically using C# on a windows client?

Tags: linux, automation, c#-4.0, administration

Can anyone show me c# code that successfully logs into a Linux server by inputting username and password?

Comment: By the way, I need each command to be initiated by C#. I want to programmatically emulate a real user logging into a Linux Server. What ever a real user would see in a terminal, is what I want my C# app to see.

Comment: What mechanism do you intend on using to communicate to the server - telnet/ssh etc...?

Comment: SSH, without ssh key authentication (ssh.exe) taken from (http://sshwindows.sourceforge.net/download/), but without installing that application. Instead, just using that ssh.exe from that application.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[sharpSsh - A Secure Shell (SSH) library for .NET](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/sharpssh.aspx)

Comment: Spot on, my brother! It won't let me vote you up until I have 15 reputation points. Sorry, thanks for the recommendation.

Comment: It is now over two years later, but today I up-voted your answer. Thanks again.