# CMD.exe C# Emulator?

Tags: c#, automation, batch-file, cmd

I've been trying very hard to automatically ssh into a Linux server. What's crazy, is that I can create a .bat script, that will do it, but I have to be there physically, to type in the password.

I've tried automating this using System.Diagnostics.Process object in c# to no end. There is no way, I've found, to make this object allow you to see the password prompt. It out puts every line up until that point, and then doesn't output any more lines.

cmd.exe, does really well at allowing you to jump from process to process in a script; It consolidates everything into one screen, and just prompts you for things such as passwords, and then you type them in.

Is there any *simple way*, in C#, to make cmd.exe think you are a human being typing in it, so I can simulated this programmatically? Otherwise, System.Diagnostics.Process, doesn't seem to offer a way to interacted with a process that outputs a password prompt. You never get to see the prompt that clearly happens when you run the same thing in cmd.exe

Comment: Have you considered setting up ssh keys to avoid the password issue? http://oreilly.com/pub/h/66

Comment: Yes, I have done this. When implemented, the batch file proceeds without a prompt. However, via System.Diagnostics.Process, the process stops outputting lines at the point where the ssh-authentication key is passed.

Comment: Perhaps the authentication is performed in another process, other than the one specified in the process object. Unlike cmd.exe, the process object loses the ability to be monitored once that process calls another.

Answer (score 2):

cmd.exe is not the SSH client; it's just a shell for one. Explore the capabilities of the actual client. In PuTTY (very popular!) there's an autologon feature, if you have an SSH key.

Comment: Agreed. You really need to look into ssh keys. They provide a secure way to login via SSH without having to type your password in each way.

Comment: I've implemented keys already. They work in cmd.exe, but in c#'s System.Diagnostics.Process object, all output (accessible through this process object) ceases right before (or during) ssh-key-authentication. In when I double-click a .bat file, though, output proceeds past authentication.

Comment: If I use that same .bat file (that doesn't get hung up), as my System.Diagnostics.Process.Filename, the process object is unable to output lines after authentication.

Comment: Why are you using a bat file? Why not call the SSH client directly with the relevant command line? With a bat file, your Process object is not the SSH client - it's the instance of CMD.exe that runs the bat file. I can envision I/O redirection becoming flakey because of this.

Answer (score 1):

You could use

Windows.Forms.SendKeys()
 to send password as keystrokes

[Reference Material](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.aspx)

Comment: The problem is, I can't get C# to even make the password prompt available. The System.Diagnostics.Process object, outputs ever line of the command line process until I expect the prompted to be output, and then stops outputting lines.

Comment: The process is setting their waiting for a password to be entered, and I have no way via System.Diagnostics.Process to access the prompt.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing which commandline tool you are using to ssh to the server, isn't there a commandline parameter to provide a password.

```
C:\> ssh user@ip -p password
```

Or have you tried input redirection:

```
ssh user@ip <
Yourpassword
EOF
```

In looking into your [earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067092/c-how-can-you-log-into-and-administer-a-linux-server-programmatically-using-c) question, what is the trouble you are having in using the programmer interface?

Are you sure you need a full fledged ssh client, or do you just want to execute a command remotely. If it is the latter you might want to check out [plink](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html).

Comment: No, ssh doesn't allow the password to be entered as a parameter. Yes, I've tried input redirection. Perhaps, the essence of the problem, is, I can't continue to interact after I authenticate.

Comment: You see, even when I've prevented having to type the password (via ssh-key-authentication), as soon as authentication occurs, I can no longer monitor line output from the System.Diagnostics.Process object.

Comment: It is like there is some kind of tricky security stuff going on at that point. I'm programmer, not a hacker. Perhaps I'm going to have to become hacker to write this program!

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Which outputs are you monitoring? Maybe the output of ssh is printed to StdErr instead of StdOut. Try adding `2>&1` to the `rsync` commandline.

Answer (score 0):

plink.exe -ssh user@host -2 -i user.ppk -m command_line.txt

How to create the ppk file: http://theillustratednetwork.mvps.org/Ssh/Private-publicKey.html